# Heroku Deployment problem AttributeError: module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation' has no attribute 'DeprecationDict'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been trying to deploy an app on Heroku, which works fine on my local but while deploying gives me the error AttributeError: module 'sklearn.utils.deprecation' has no attribute 'DeprecationDict'

Comment: check your requirements.txt file `sklearn` package is `0.0`

Comment: I changed the scikit-learn==0.23.2 to scikit-learn==0.19.1 in the requirements.txt and it worked.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can upvote comment/answer/question

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem arose because the sklearn version used to train the model was old, whereas the version used by Heroku to load the model was the newer one, so need to make sure the requirement.txt has the same version used to train the model.